# Parsing XML data from URL variable in PHP and WordPress

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I have a PHP page that a service sends out a notice when a donation is made. My PHP page is supposed to grab the XML contents and parse it out for processing.

The service sends the following format:

```
http://myserver.com/myphp.com?details= xml data
```

I have the following code listening for this post:

```
//Load xml from post
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$xmlData = simplexml_load_string($data);
//grab mobile number to query mgive for user info
$mnumb= $xmlData->MobileNumber;
$mnumb=ltrim($mnumb,'1');
```

I am getting the following error when the service sends out the notice.
Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in

what am I missing or coding wrong?

12-18-2013  855cst
Thanks ThW.. Progress is being made.

I used your suggestion #2 to get the data.
When I do a print_r(xmlData), I get no output on the screen.  However, when using chrome developer tool, I get the following output:
data=%3C%3Fxml+version%3D%221.0%22+encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%3CGetDonationStatusResult+xmlns%3Axsi%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema-instance%22+xmlns%3Axsd%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%3E%3CResultCode+%3E0%3C%2FResultCode%3E%3CResultText+%2F%3E%3CRecordID+%3E0%3C%2FRecordID%3E%3CMobileNumber+%3E12142911111%3C%2FMobileNumber%3E%3CCarrierID+%3E31002%3C%2FCarrierID%3E%3CCarrierName+%3EAT%26amp%3BT+Wireless%3C%2FCarrierName%3E%3CDonationStatus+%3EUserAccepted%3C%2FDonationStatus%3E%3CMobileTransactionID+%3E62622731%3C%2FMobileTransactionID%3E%3CDonationMsgGUID+%3E9c17d57f-b54e-488a-8cf5-1c658d1aa618%3C%2FDonationMsgGUID%3E%3CCampaignID+%3E20409%3C%2FCampaignID%3E%3CShortCode+%3E27722%3C%2FShortCode%3E%3CMsgTime+%3E2013-12-17T12%3A53%3A18%3C%2FMsgTime%3E%3CMessageText+%3ELIBERIA+WAP%3C%2FMessageText%3E%3C%2FGetDonationStatusResult%3E&*****

You can see MobileNumber is sent.  But, when I echo $mnumb, I get no output.  Am I missing something in my use of simplexml_load_string($data); to grab the MobileNumber?

Comment: Can you show an example with the XML you're actually passing to it?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><GetDonationStatusResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><ResultCode >0</ResultCode><ResultText /><RecordID >0</RecordID><MobileNumber >19191112222</MobileNumber><CarrierID >31002</CarrierID><CarrierName >AT&amp;T Wireless</CarrierName><DonationStatus >UserAccepted</DonationStatus><MsgTime >2013-12-17T20:53:05</MsgTime><MessageText >LIBERIA WAP</MessageText></GetDonationStatusResult>

Comment: Is that exactly what you get when you echo `$data;`? You are 100% sure?

Comment: That code was taken from a log provided by the service that sent the notification

Comment: I am told it is after the detail= in the URL.

Comment: This is from a description in the documentation describing the callback function:URL to call (POST, XML data is in the data= parameter

Comment: Basically, I need the mobilenumber from the xml data in a URL variable name data(not details as stated above).

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear where you get the xml data from.

1. Read from the detail parameter in the url `$xml = $_GET['detail'];`
2. Read from the data parameter in the url `$xml = $_GET['data'];`
3. Read from the data parameter in the request body (post) `$xml = $_POST['data'];`
4. Read the raw post data `$xml = file_get_contents("php://input");`

Try to var_dump() the data:

```
var_dump($_GET, $_POST);
```

After you got the XML into a variable use DOM + Xpath to extract values from it:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetDonationStatusResult xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ResultCode >0</ResultCode>
  <ResultText />
  <RecordID >0</RecordID>
  <MobileNumber >19191112222</MobileNumber>
  <CarrierID >31002</CarrierID>
  <CarrierName >AT&amp;T Wireless</CarrierName>
  <DonationStatus >UserAccepted</DonationStatus>
  <MsgTime >2013-12-17T20:53:05</MsgTime>
  <MessageText >LIBERIA WAP</MessageText>
</GetDonationStatusResult>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
// try to load the xml
if ($dom->loadXml($xml)) {
  $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
  // read the first MobileNumber element as string
  var_dump(
    $xpath->evaluate('string(//MobileNumber)')
  );
}
```

Output:

```
string(11) "19191112222"
```

[Live Result](https://eval.in/80879)

Comment: Good answer, but he's already using the SimpleXML object, no need to worry about making DOM objects (unless we want to make CDATA elements ;) )

Comment: SimpleXML is quite limited and only a wrapper around DOMDocument. It's xpath() method can not return scalar values for example. I am to lazy to use it.

Comment: Too lazy? SimpleXML and using the underlying DOMDocument combined is the most productive way, I've found, to process XML of smaller datasets in PHP. And what do you mean  by xpath not being able to return scalar values? That's not really the purpose of it.

Comment: The result of a xpath expression is an XPathResult ( http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html#XPathResult), this includes scalars. Using Xpath and DOM directly is less and more stable source in the most cases. In the current question, load an XML without an MobileNumber element.

Comment: I know what the result of an xpath expression is in the standard form, so I'm not sure what you're getting at there.

Comment: Not sure if I did this right.. but I edited my original message to add some information based on what @Thw suggested...

Comment: I extended the answer to show that the DOM part works. Try to debug your request data.